# What is the upper file count limit for concatenating files using MsConcat?

Tags: azure-data-lake

We are thinking to use the MsConcat function to merge a large number of small files stored in Azure Data Lake Store. I am wondering if there is any limit on a number of files. I have not seen any information about any limit on number of files in [documentation](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-datalake-store/latest/FileSystem.html#msConcat).

Comment: It may be that you do not need to physically concatenate the files as U-SQL has a concept called [filesets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771650.aspx).  Please tell us a bit more about your requirement ( eg type of files, content, desired outcome ) first.

Comment: As I said, I want to merge large number(10K to 20K) of small files as a first step using MsConcat. In next step, I will be using filesets pattern for processing merged files for U-SQL processing.

Comment: @Jamil This is a valid question and I will get back to you on this shortly.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni Any update on this?

Comment: @Jamil. Apologies for the delay. I am still working on getting the accurate value for this.

Comment: Is this definitely the right approach? Surely you can just use the file name as a wild card in your extractor which we combine the datasets for you?

Comment: @PaulAndrew I learned, there is a limit on file sets, and it does not work well with a large number of small files.

Comment: @Jamil also note that combining files via msconcat does not help in optimizing read performance. We strongly recommend against storing and concatenating really small files. The better choice if you have it is to aggregate the data to store larger files in the first place. Where are you sourcing the data from?

Answer (score 0):

The msconcat API is designed to concatenate up to 500 files. In most typical cases, it should work okay for operations of this size. There are some uncommon cases, such as when the system is under high load, when you may see failures for 500 files or under. However these are not expected during normal operations.